# sql-server-2012 beginner please advise, intellisense not recognizing tables (already refreshed cache)

Tags: sql-server-2012

Sorry for the edits.  I originally had a problem with syntax, however now I don't know how to update tables - the trigger does not seem to run when I update, insert, delete records from the orginal.

Trigger for calculating totals (similar for DELETE and UPDATE):

```
CREATE TRIGGER employeeTotal
ON employeeTotals
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS BEGIN
SELECT SUM(sold) FROM sales AS totalSales
...same here for totalPurchases/totalHours...
END
```

I also have a trigger for hours worked which is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER employeeWorked
ON employeeTimes
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS BEGIN
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOURS,clockIn,clockOut) FROM employeeTimes AS timeIntimeOutTotal
END
```

It may be obvious I am not familiar with SQL-server-2012 anyone who might know why no tables are recognized, now tables are not updating eventhough there are no errors creating triggers.  Any ideas?

Edit - I restarted the VM and the second trigger worked!  I changed the first to as below pls let me know if it is significantly erroneous.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER employeeTotal
ON employeeTotals
FOR INSERT
AS BEGIN
SELECT SUM(sold) FROM sales AS totalSales
...same here for totalPurchases/totalHours...
END
```

Comment: what's the database compatibility level?

Comment: I really don't have any idea, how do I view that?  Sorry just started with this today.

Comment: Your 2nd trigger has no `FROM` line...

Comment: assuming you have the permissions, right click the database, go to properties and then Options

Comment: compatibility level is at sql-2012 (110)...  Also whenever I select the table from the drop down menu in query box, it still says table does not exist or is not valid for the operation

Comment: then using Ctrl + Shift + R should work

Comment: Thanks guys I believe I solved it if I should post my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CTRL + SHIFT + R, this is how it was done in Sql Server 2014.

Comment: Yes, table still show with error (don't exist or not valid)

Answer (score 0):

try yo use red geate sql prompt it too good and fast intellosence for sql server i use it for 2 yrars and withoutcot i cant use ssms